# What a struct/class has to implement to work with many (if not all) STL features when it's inside a container?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, c++17

For example, if I have a struct to hold some information like this:

```cpp
struct Two {
  int a, b;
}
```

I don't want to use a tuple and I can't use C++20 and `<=>` (the highest I can go is C++17).

Then what is the minimum set of operand overloads (and other functions) I have to implement to make it work with all (or most of the) STL algorithms and containers?

If I will assume the user will **not** do any operation on his own, like these:

```cpp
Two a(1,2);
Two b(2,3);
const float c = 1.4;

a *= b;
a *= 2;
a += c;
```

And I do not want to provide anything extra implementation for the user's convenience, only to support the STL.

Is there a documentation page similar to https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/ summarizing them in one document and what they need to have implemented to function?

Comment: Even if you class doesn't have `operator <`, you might provide custom comparer/hash to `std::set`/`std::find`/..

Comment: The non-replaceable properties are copy/move constructible/assignable (with `noexcept`).

Comment: This is something you should look up in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: Then, for each classes/algorithms, there are requirements for the type in standard and in doc.

Comment: *" I have to implement the - operator so it can compare the diff to know if it's bigger/smaller."*. No [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) requires [comparable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) types (via `operator <`)/comparer functor.

Comment: `std::unordered_set<Two, hashFunction> exist; std::sort(exist.begin(), exist.end());` is a non-starter for all types, you can't modify the elements of an `unordered_set`

Comment: @Jarod42 ok, but my point is, is there a table/list in a documentation listing all of these (find, sort, max_element ....) and what they really need?

Comment: As I said, there are "Type requirements" in doc of [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Comment: your edit invalidated parts of the answer. Please do not change the question to ask for something else after you recieved answers. Note that the answer did already refer to the case of a container that is actually sortable ("Subtraction operator isn't necessary to sort objects. What you need is a way to compare them...") , ie the vector case doesnt add something new, but only breaks parts of the answer.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The parts of the answer which were invalidated are not part of the question. The answers here are about technicalities of the flawed examples I gave. But the main point of the question is not really answered. I do not know what STL features will be used in advance so I can't just go to look at documentation of std::find, yet I would like to know if there is a completely list and their requirements what they need implemented.

Comment: @Jarod42 They are just my bad examples, I do not know if user will use std::find or something else, how I can find out list of the STL features and what they need without really knowing that will be used in the advance. My guess is if I could use C++20 and use `<=>` I would be well covered for a lot of things. Just I'm stuck with C++17

Comment: maybe it wasnt part of the question you wanted to ask, but it was part of the quesiton you did ask and that the answer adressed.

Answer (score 3):

> Note: Yes for this example using a `Tuple<int, int>` would be more suiting

I disagree. Tuple lacks the ability to give a name for the type and for the members. That is a significant drawback in most cases.

> Let's give it default and initializing constructors:
>
> ```
>   Two(void): a(0), b(0) {
>   }
>
>   Two(int x, int y): a(x), b(y) {
>   }
> ```

I recommend against this in most cases. Aggregate classes are useful.

> have to implement my hashFunction. If I understand it correctly that applies to set, map and unordered_map.

No, you don't need a hash function for set nor map. You only need a hash function for unordered containers. For set and map, the keys must be orderable instead.

> If I then use this unordered_set, but want to order it:
>
> ```
> std::unordered_set<Two, hashFunction> exist;
> std::sort(exist.begin(), exist.end());
> ```

This isn't possible. You cannot sort unordered containers (the clue is in the name). The iterators of the set are const.

> Then I have to implement the - operator so it can compare the diff to know if it's bigger/smaller.

Subtraction operator isn't necessary to sort objects. What you need is a way to compare them. This can be done with a less-than operator, but it isn't necessary since you may use a comparison functor instead (just like you used a hash functor in your example).

> If I want to use .find on this set:
>
> ```
> auto it = exist.find(Two(i, index)
> ```
>
> Then I have to implement the == operator:

Equality comparison is a general requirement of the unordered containers whether you want to use find or not. The equality operator isn't required if you use an equality comparator functor instead.

> then how I could know what to implement in the advance?

You don't need to know, because the standard containers and algorithms support custom functors for all such functionality. The user of the class can implement those in any way they prefer.

But you can implement all the operators expected from regular types for convenience of the user of the class. I recommend adding all relational operators like this (C++20 required):

```
struct Two {
    int a, b;
    friend auto operator<=>(const Two&, const Two&) = default;
};
```

In general, you can know what standard library containers and algorithms require by reading their documentation.

> if we are using at max C++17 ?

Then you must implement each comparison operator explicitly. Only less-than and equality are used by standard library containers, but it's convenient to have all. You can reduce boilerplate by using a base class such as those from Boost.Operators library.

Comment: @Jarod42 I added a mention.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, the `unordered_set` can't be sorted, changed that to a vector, just to highlight that when sorting is used it wants some specific operator.

Comment: "I disagree. Tuple lacks the ability to give a name for the type and for the members. That is a significant drawback in most cases." I agree with you on this, just I was worried that people would be stuck up on the technicalities of the question (you could use tuple instead) and avoiding the main question, is there some table/list for the STL features (find, sort, max_element ...) and what they really need?

Comment: The spaceship is perfect, just for the case if we are using at max C++17 ? I do not want the user to have implement anything extra and the user doesn't need to use anything other than the STL, what would be the minim implementation to work well with the STL features?

Comment: @AntonKrug: It depends of what you want your type does? Should they be used by `std::sort`, [`std::lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock), as iterator, ... We might say just `operator <` and `==`, but cannot be used as key of `std::unordered_map`. if not default constructible, you cannot use `operator[]` of `map`, ... It really depends of what you want to do/provide for your class.

Comment: @Jarod42 exactly, and that's what I'm wondering about. For example, containers have a nice summary page https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/ and I wonder if there a summary document for knowing what you need to implement to make it work with that STL feature. My guess is that you do not need to implement 100% of the operands, so what is the minimal implementation to support the STL features.